# accessing fortran type bound subroutines across all instances of the type

Tags: oop, types, fortran

Can someone explain how I might access type bound subroutines across multiple instances of a type without iterating over each instance? In the code below, I have an allocatable 2d array (i.e., 'grid') of instances of the 'cell' type, which has variable var1. I can easily access var1 across all instances of the grid (e.g., grid%var1) returns an array of var1 values across the grid. However, I cannot call a type bound subroutine (called 'compute') unless I iterate over every instance of cell and call individually. Is there any way that this can be done without iterating over the grid?

```
module cellmodule

  implicit none
  
  type :: cell 
    real :: var1 = 0
    contains
      procedure, public :: compute 
  end type  

Contains

  subroutine compute(this)
    class(cell) :: this
    this%var1 = this%var1 + 1
  end subroutine compute

end module cellmodule

module modelmodule

  use cellmodule
  type :: model 
    type(cell), allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: grid
  end type 

end module modelmodule 

program testprogram

  use cellmodule
  use modelmodule
  implicit none 
  
  integer :: x = 2
  integer :: y = 2
  Integer :: i, j
  type(model) :: m
  allocate(m%grid(x,y))
  
  !I can access var1 across all instances of the cell type like
  print*, m%grid%var1
  m%grid%var1 = m%grid%var1 + 1.0
  print*, m%grid%var1

  !I can also iterate over the grid and call compute for each cell
  do i = 1, x
    do j = 1, y
      call m%grid(i,j)%compute
    End do
  End do
  print*, m%grid%var1

  !HOWEVER, I can't do this:
  call m%grid%compute
  print*, m%grid%var1
  
end program
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but declaring the routine `compute` as `elemental` may do.

Comment: I have just tried, yes it does. By doing so, you have also to specify `intent(inout)` the argument `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the subroutine as `elemental` (which in turn requires `intent()` to be specified for the arguments.

```
  elemental subroutine compute(this)
    class(cell), intent(inout) :: this
    this%var1 = this%var1 + 1
  end subroutine compute
```